# Make private enum values

Tags: c, forward

In `C` you can make enumerations like this:

```c
enum {
    key_1    = 1,
    key_2    = 2,
    key_3    = 4
};
```

The problem that I have found is, when you place this in a public header, you cannot ensure that the values in the pre compiled implementation do match with the public header. For example:

```c
enum lvls {
    debuglvl_debug       = 0x01
    debuglvl_info        = 0x02,
    debuglvl_warning     = 0x04,
    debuglvl_error       = 0x08,
    /* And so on... */
    debuglvl_all         = 0xFF
};
```

If you would now do this in your code (private):

```c
if (flags & debuglvl_error) {
    /* Do something when debuglvl_error flag is set */
}
```

There is no guarantee that `debuglvl_error` will have the value `0x08` because it can be easily changed in the header file (of course its now questionable if you would to change these values but I'm just asking for nosiness). So.. is there way to make enum values private? Something like this:

public header file:

```c
 enum lvls {
      debuglvl_debug,
      debuglvl_info,
      debuglvl_warning,
      debuglvl_error,
      debuglvl_all
 };
```

private implementation:

```c
 enum lvls {
    debuglvl_debug       = 0x01
    debuglvl_info        = 0x02,
    debuglvl_warning     = 0x04,
    debuglvl_error       = 0x08,
    debuglvl_all         = 0xFF
 };
```

My compiler does not let me do that, so is there another workaround for this? I guess its impossible to do so: do I need to rely on the fact that my header files are always unchanged?

Comment: Why would someone want to break it by changing the header? Or is this a question about versioning where someone has a different version of the header?

Comment: Is about both, versioning and outside change (for whatever reason).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing isn't possible for an `enum` as it goes against what an `enum` is.  For what you want, you should just do variables with external linkage.

header file:

```
extern const int debug_debug, debug_info,...;
```

implementation file:

```
const int debug_debug = 0x01, debug_info = 0x02,...;
```

And for added security you can use the GCC's attribute syntax `__attribute__((section("rodata")))` to place the variable in readonly memory.